# Make IIS proxy aware for a .net 6 API cert auth

Tags: .net, proxy, iis-7, x509certificate, iis-8

I have an API that requires to authenticate with a client certificate. When the request comes from outside, we get a revocation error that the cert revocation URL was not reached. From the same server, if I go login.. through proxy I am able to reach to that url but the IIS or the server itself can not reach to it.

I have tried to put this in the config but to no luck:

```
<system.net>  
    <defaultProxy>  
      <proxy  
        usesystemdefault="True"  
        proxyaddress="http://192.168.1.10:3128"  
        bypassonlocal="True"  
      />  
      <bypasslist>  
        <add address="[a-z]+\.contoso\.com$" />  
      </bypasslist>  
    </defaultProxy>  
  </system.net>
```

I also tried the header forwarding options in my code found here: [MS .NET 6.0 Proxy config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: What you changed on .NET side is irrelevant, as most of IIS components are native, not managed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/security-privacy/description-of-cryptography-api-proxy-from-crl See if you can change at WinHTTP level for application pool identity/machine account.

Comment: I actually fixed this couple of an hour ago. The issue was as you stated above WinHTTP and I used netsh winhttp to set the proxy for win http service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

using netsh I set my proxy on winhttp services.
That fixed it.